# Difference between relatively and comparatively?

Tags: word-usage

I have some problem about the use of “comparatively” and “relatively”.
For example
Power has comparatively greater effect on echo changes in the upper layer. 
Or
Power has relatively greater effect on echo changes in the upper layer.
I want to show the effect of power on echo changes in upper layer with respect to lower layer. I want to write the sentence as shown above but dont know which sentence is correct. Any guidance will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two have a similar meaning, but, with relatively, the things it's relative **to** can more easily be implied, rather than specified.  With "comparatively" you'd expect to know what it's compared to.  In other words, you should only use "comparatively" when **you are making a direct comparison**, whereas "relatively" can be used in a more general sense.

For example, if I say "There's been a relatively high rainfall this year", the reader would understand that I mean "compared to other years, generally".

But, if I say "There's been a comparatively high rainfall this year", it begs the question "Compared to what?".